# How can I show the output of two print statements on the same line?

Tags: python

I have 2 separate print statements:

print "123"

print "456"

How can i make these 2 print statement appear on the same line?
Note i need to use 2 print statements

output:

123456

Comment: "I need to use 2 print statements"... why?

Comment: Related post - [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/465053)

Answer (score 7):

In python 1.x and 2.x, a trailing comma will do what you want (with the caveat mentioned by others about the extra space inserted):

```
print "123",
print "456"
```

In python 3.x — or in python 2.6-2.7 with `from __future__ import print_function` — `print` is a function and you should use `end=""` to force no extra ending character:

```
print("123", end="")
print("456")
```

Comment: Python 1.x? Seriously? I don't think there are any installations of this left (and even if, they should be nuked from the orbit).

Comment: @delnan: Yes there are and yes they should be.

Answer (score 6):

A comma after the string you are printing will suppress the newline. The `\b` is a special character that represents an ASCII backspace.

```
print '123',
print '\b456'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
print "123",
print "456"
```

Alternatively, you can use `sys.stdout.write`:

```
sys.stdout.write('123')
sys.stdout.write('456\n')
```

Answer (score 4):

```
print '123',
print '\b456'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print "123",
print "456"
```

For Python 3+

```
print("123", end="")
print("456")
```