# How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read that to suppress the newline after a print statement you can put a comma after the text. The example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4390955/1343005) looks like Python 2. **How can it be done in Python 3?**

For example:

```
for item in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(item, " ")
```

What needs to change so that it prints them on the same line?

Comment: You could just do `print(' '.join([str(i) for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]]))`

Comment: `print(*[1, 2, 3, 4])` works for the common case of printing a space separated sequence

Comment: Related post - [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386/465053). The accepted answer in this thread covers all Python versions.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The question asks: "**How can it be done in Python 3?**"

Use this construct with Python 3.x:

```
for item in [1,2,3,4]:
    print(item, " ", end="")
```

This will generate:

```
1  2  3  4
```

See this [Python doc](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) for more information:

```
Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```

--

*Aside*:

in addition, the `print()` function also offers the `sep` parameter that lets one specify how individual items to be printed should be separated. E.g.,

```
In [21]: print('this','is', 'a', 'test')  # default single space between items
this is a test

In [22]: print('this','is', 'a', 'test', sep="") # no spaces between items
thisisatest

In [22]: print('this','is', 'a', 'test', sep="--*--") # user specified separation
this--*--is--*--a--*--test
```

Comment: Perfect! So end="" just overrides the newline character.

Comment: @ChrisHarris See the update with the quote from the docs, so you are replacing the newline with `""` (the empty string)

Comment: Everywhere I look everyone says to do end='', but I get: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @thang What version of Python are you using? This works for version 3.x

Comment: @Levon, 2.7.  Probably a version issue, but I need backwards compatibility :(  Guess I am stuck with sys.stdout.write

Comment: @thang You might want to look at the "from future import print", not sure that will fix your problem, but it just might http://python-future.org/quickstart.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075082/what-is-future-in-python-used-for-and-how-when-to-use-it-and-how-it-works

Comment: To be more specific, it's `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: @ScottStafford Good point, thanks for helping point out that detail

Answer (score 5):

**Code for Python 3.6.1**

```
print("This first text and " , end="")

print("second text will be on the same line")

print("Unlike this text which will be on a newline")
```

**Output**

```
>>>
This first text and second text will be on the same line
Unlike this text which will be on a newline
```

Comment: This clarified how the end="" parameter would affect the next line, but not the one after that - thanks!

Answer (score 4):

print didn't transition from statement to function until Python 3.0.  If you're using older Python then you can suppress the newline with a trailing comma like so:

```
print "Foo %10s bar" % baz,
```

Comment: The question specifically asked about using Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Because python 3 print() function allows end="" definition, that satisfies the majority of issues.

In my case, I wanted to PrettyPrint and was frustrated that this module wasn't similarly updated.   So i made it do what i wanted:

```
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

class CommaEndingPrettyPrinter(PrettyPrinter):
    def pprint(self, object):
        self._format(object, self._stream, 0, 0, {}, 0)
        # this is where to tell it what you want instead of the default "\n"
        self._stream.write(",\n")

def comma_ending_prettyprint(object, stream=None, indent=1, width=80, depth=None):
    """Pretty-print a Python object to a stream [default is sys.stdout] with a comma at the end."""
    printer = CommaEndingPrettyPrinter(
        stream=stream, indent=indent, width=width, depth=depth)
    printer.pprint(object)
```

Now, when I do:

```
comma_ending_prettyprint(row, stream=outfile)
```

I get what I wanted (substitute what you want -- Your Mileage May Vary)

Answer (score 0):

There's some information on printing without newline [here](https://buildvirtual.net/python-print-without-newline/).

In Python 3.x we can use ‘end=’ in the print function. This tells it to end the string with a character of our choosing rather than ending with a newline. For example:

```
print("My 1st String", end=","); print ("My 2nd String.")
```

This results in:

```
My 1st String, My 2nd String.
```