# Print statements without new lines in python?

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a way to print elements without newlines such as

```
x=['.','.','.','.','.','.']

for i in x:
    print i
```

and that would print `........` instead of what would normally print which would be

```
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This can be easily done with the [print()](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) *function* with **Python 3**.

```
for i in x:
  print(i, end="")  # substitute the null-string in place of newline
```

will give you

```
......
```

In **Python v2** you can use the `print()` function by including:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

as the *first* statement in your source file.

As the [print() docs](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) state:

```
Old: print x,           # Trailing comma suppresses newline
New: print(x, end=" ")  # Appends a space instead of a newline
```

Note, this is similar to a recent question I answered ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/12102758/1209279 ) that contains some additional information about the `print()` function if you are curious.

Comment: Note that this will only work in Python 3 or when you have `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of your file.

Comment: @omz Yes that is correct - I was just adding a note about that while you were posting your comment.

Answer (score 9):

```
import sys
for i in x:
    sys.stdout.write(i)
```

or

```
print ''.join(x)
```

Answer (score 6):

I surprised no one has mentioned the pre-Python3 method for suppressing the newline: a trailing comma.

```
for i in x:
    print i,
print  # For a single newline to end the line
```

This does insert spaces before certain characters, as is explained [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#print).

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can either print with sys.stdout.write, or using a trailing comma after the print to do the space, but another way to print a list with whatever seperator you want is a join:

```
print "".join(['.','.','.'])
# ...
print "foo".join(['.','.','.'])
#.foo.foo.
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python3:

```
for i in x:
    print(i,end="")
```