# Python3: Using "select.select" with print(str, end=' ')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using select.select() instead of input because I wanted a timeout for the input. I am using the "end" argument with the print() function because I want my terminal to have a line like this:

Type > *TYPE SOMETHING HERE*

Instead, I do not see "Type > " until after I type a string and press enter.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#Made by Devyn Collier Johnson, NCLA, Linux+, LPIC-1, DCTS
import sys, select

print('Type > ', end=" ")
INPUT, VOID0, VOID1 = select.select([sys.stdin], [], [], 3)

if (INPUT):
    print('You said, ' + sys.stdin.readline().strip())
else:
    print('You said nothing!')
```

I am using this script to test select.select() and print(str, end=" "). I read this post ([How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/in-python-3-how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement-with-the-comm)) and the official Python3 documentation for both commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` is buffered by default, to force it to display you need to flush it:

```
print('Type > ', end='')
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Note that `print` also supports this via keyword arguments:

```
print('Type > ', end='', flush=True)
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked well. I cannot mark your answer until seven minutes has passed. I will keep this tab open on my browser so I can mark your answer.

Comment: @DevynCollierJohnson No worries - I take it, it's no coincidence I got an upvote for an answer with that select statement and then this question turns up :)