# How can I group while outputs into a single string?

Tags: python, string, encryption

This is a simple encryption code that I've come up with. It uses a single character key.

```
ar = input('please input string to be de/encrypted:')
key = input('please input single character key:')

def encrypt1(key,ar):
    i = 0
    while i < len(ar):
        br = chr(ord(ar[i])^ord(key))
        i = i+1
        print(br)

encrypt1(key,ar)

print('Input string = ' + ar+'\n'+'key = '+key)
```

If I input "CMPUT" for the string to be encrypted and 'a' as the key I will get this printed output:

```
"
,
1
4
5
```

Which is the correct encryption (according to my assignment example). Now I just have to get those outputs into a single string and print them in the shell like such:

```
>>>decrypted string: ",145
```

I've looked through google and old questions on this website but I've still come up empty. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this code, I believe this is what you need (I changed `print(br)` line):

```
ar = input('please input string to be de/encrypted:')
key = input('please input single character key:')

def encrypt1(key,ar):
    i = 0
    while i < len(ar):
        br = chr(ord(ar[i])^ord(key))
        i = i+1
        print(br, end='')

encrypt1(key,ar)

print('\nInput string = ' + ar+'\n'+'key = '+key)
```

Comment: I change last line in my example, that should fix the problem. (Simply add `\n`)

Comment: I literally just figured that out before you posted it (thank god for google). Thanks for your help. This works the best. I would upvote but I'm new to this website.

Answer (score 0):

Most obvious way for a beginner would be to simply accumulate to a string

```
def encrypt1(key,ar):
    i = 0
    result = ""
    while i < len(ar):
        br = chr(ord(ar[i])^ord(key))
        i = i+1
        result += br
    return result
```

Usually you would just write it using a generator expression

```
def encrypt1(key,ar):
    return ''.join(chr(ord(i) ^ ord(key)) for i in ar)
```

Comment: Thanks! I used part of this code as well as the above.