# Putting integers in tabular form without whitespace in Python

Tags: python, string, removing-whitespace

Sorry that I ask this here, because this seems really elementary and is most likely asked before. However, I have been searching and trying for hours and I couldn't find anything that helped me out. I want to write a program that asks for an upper bound and returns a table with pairs of numbers (m,n) such that the sum of of divisors of n (excluding n) equals m, and vice versa.

Now I wrote the following

```
bound = int(input('upper bound = '))
l = len(str(bound))
for x in range(1,l):
    print(' ', end='')
print('m', end='  ')
for y in range(1,l):
    print(' ', end='')
print('n', end='')
for i in range(1,bound):
    for j in range (1, bound):
        if j == i:
            break
        som_i = 0
        som_j = 0
        for k in range(1,i):
            if i % k == 0:
                som_i += k
        for l in range(1,j):
            if j % l == 0:
                som_j += l
        if som_i == j and som_j == i:
            print('{:{prec}d}'.format(j, prec = l).rstrip(''), end="")
            print('{:{prec}d}'.format(i, prec = l+2).lstrip(''), end="")
```

The problem is that I want the pair to be displayed in tabular form side to side and with the right indentation, depending on the length of the number. Whatever I tried (I read so many treads with similar questions already) Python keeps adding a whitespace.

Can anyone help me out on this? I am really new to Python and I cannot figure this out myself. If relevant,  I am using version 3.6.

EDIT:

For example, when I run the program I get:

```
upper bound = 300
  m    n        
220
284
```

while I would like to get

```
upper bound = 300
  m    n        
220  284
```

And similar for larger inputs.

**EDIT2** My question is not a duplicate, since i already tried adding

```
end=""
```

which did not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I tried that already before posting and that method did not work.

Comment: Edit your question to include the `end=""`, and to show the (reproducible) results of running it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem is that you're not using `end=''` after printing the `j` value, but you apparently already know about that. You also *are* using it after printing the `n` header, which you don't want.

Your edited version fixes the missing `end=''` after the `j` print, but then adds one after the `i` print, which, again, you don't want.

I'm not sure you understand what `end=''` means, so you're just putting it into your code randomly. That isn't going to get you very far. You can read the docs for [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), but the short version is: use `end=''` when you're printing something that isn't supposed to be the end of a line, like that `m` header and `j` value, but *don't* use it when you're printing something that *is* supposed to be the end of a line, like that `n` header and `i` value.

---

The second problem is that `l` is just way too big. After `for l in range(1,j):`, it's going to be the same value as `j`, which means it's going to be 219, so you're going to print that `220` filled out to 219 characters, and that `284` filled out to 221 characters. So, unless your terminal is more than 446 characters wide, it's going to scroll across multiple lines and look like a mess. I think what you may want here is to use `3` and `5`.

Or, maybe, you have some other variable that's supposed to be 3, and you want to use (let's call that variable `x`) `x` and `x+2` instead of `l` and `l+2`. But I don't see any obvious candidates in your code.

So:

```
# ... unchanged lines
print('n') # no end='' here
# ... more unchanged lines
        # using 3 and 5 instead of l and l+2, and adding end=''
        print(('{:{prec}d}'.format(j, prec = 3)).rstrip(''), end='')
        print(('{:{prec}d}'.format(i, prec = 5)).lstrip(''))
```

And now, the output is:

```
upper bound = 300
  m    n
220  284
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, I really appreciate your help. And again sorry if my question was not clear but I'm really new to Python so I had a hard time explaining this properly. There were a few mistakes with the 'end' command. I thought I understood it properly, but I didn't. The big mistake however, was by choosing 'l' somewhere in in a for loop, while I defined 'l' as the length of the input.