# Printing Fibonacci sequence on a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input('How many terms you want to Generate: '))

i = 1
j = 1
k = 0
print(i,j)
while k < n:
    j += i
    print(j, end=" ")
    i = j-i
    k += 1
```

The first two numbers are printed on the first line and all other are printed on the second line. I tried to append all in one list but it gives me error.

Comment: What is the error? What is your expected results? What is your current result?

Comment: this code gives output like this: 1,1 \n 2,3,5,8,13... Hope you understand.

Comment: What is the error? What is your expected results?

Comment: Which python version you are using? On 3.6 its printing on single line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You correctly provided the argument `end=" "` to `print` inside your loop, but forgot about it for the `print` before your loop.

```
n = int(input('How many terms you want to Generate: '))

i = 1
j = 1
k = 0
print(i, j, end=" ")
while k < n:
    j += i
    print(j, end=" ")
    i = j-i
    k += 1
```

Output:

```
How many terms you want to Generate: 5
1 1 2 3 5 8 13
```

Although, note that your solution still does not print the correct number of elements.

### Improvements

More elegants solutions exist using generators, which are well-suited to represent infinite sequences.

```
import itertools

def fib():
    a, b = 1, 1
    while True:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b

n = int(input('How many terms you want to Generate: '))
print(*itertools.islice(fib(), n))
```

Output:

```
How many terms you want to Generate: 5
1 1 2 3 5
```