# Print straight line while looping- Python 3

Tags: python, loops, printing, nested

I have a cardgame, and I want to print it in this format:

```
0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8
2♠  6♣  10♣ Q♦  2♦  3♦  9♣  5♣  8♣
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4
```

Currently my code is like this:

```
 for i in stacks:
            print(counter1)#Gives each card a number 
            print(i[-1].value, i[-1].suit)#Cards gotten out from nested list
            print(len(i), end=" ")#Tells how many cards left in the deck
counter1 += 1 #It gives each card a number.
```

and the result prints it downwards.
What can I do to improve? I tried sep and end, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Originally I had the code like this:

```
print(counter1, "      ",  i[-1].value, i[-1].suit, "      ", len(i))
```

But I'm trying to find the best solution

Im working on Python 3
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is counter1 variable? pls post little more of your code

Comment: updated the edit now! (y)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I suppress the newline after a print statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102749/how-can-i-suppress-the-newline-after-a-print-statement)

Comment: You need to print ALL counters, then print all value/suits, then print all cards-left-in-deck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 different `for` for this.

```
for i in stacks:
            print(counter1, end='   ')#Gives each card a number 
            counter1 += 1
print()
for i in stacks:
            print(i[-1].value, i[-1].suit,  end='  ')#Cards gotten out from nested list
print()
for i in stacks:
            print(len(i),  end='   ')#Tells how many cards left in the deck
print()
```