# How to print things and put them in the same line in Python

Tags: python, newline

how do I print two things in one row so that it isn't in a new line

```
print ("alright " + name)
howareyou = input("How are you?: ")

if howareyou == "good" or "Good" or "Alright" or "GOOD" or "bad" or "BAD":
    print ("Alright")
else:
    print ("What is that?")
```

When I run it

```
alright 
How are you?:
```

So, how do I put them in the same line?

Comment: Also:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/4390942/748858 (for python2.x)

Comment: On a side note, you are using the `or` operator incorrectly.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/if-x-or-y-or-z-blah) for reference.

Comment: Ok thanks guys but i got it:                                          howareyou = input("Alright " + name + " how are you?: ")

Answer (score 5):

python2:

```
print "hello",
print "there"
```

note the trailing comma. A trailing comma after a print statement suppresses the newline   character. Note also that we do not put a space on the end of hello -- a trailing comma for print also puts a space after the string.

It works even in the compound statement with multiple strings:
python2:

```
print "hello", "there", "henry",
print "!"
```

prints:

```
hello there henry !
```

In python3:

```
print("hello ", end=' ')
print("there", end='')
```

the default value of the end parameter for the print function is '\n', which is the newline character. So in python3 you suppress the newline character yourself by specifying the end character to be an empty string.

Note: You can use **any string** as the end symbol:

```
print("hello", end='LOL')
print("there", end='')
```

prints:

```
helloLOLthere
```

You could, for instance, make end=' ' to avoid adding spaces to the end of your printed string. That's very useful :)

```
print("hello", end=' ')
print("there", end='')
```

Comment: And, to finish this off, to comply with python2.6+, you could use the python3 version with `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3:

```
print('Some stuff', end='')
```

In Python 2:

```
print 'Some stuff',
```